# How to get the content of a tag inside a label

Tags: jquery, html

How can get the content of the b tag?

```
<label for="onde">
    <b>qua qua text</b>
    <textarea name="onde"></textarea>
</label>
```

I am trying this with no success:

```
$('textarea[name=onde]').prev().val();
```

Comment: Btw the `for` attribute doesn't apply on elements with `name` attributes. You have to specify an `id` attribute on the TEXTAREA if you want the LABEL to be associated with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('label[for="onde"] b').text();
```

should do it

Answer (score 4):

You were close:

```
$( 'textarea[name="onde"]' ).prev().text()
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/5Y3Q8/